# Update is not applicable to your computer in windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2008-r2

Im installing the KB4012212 patch to a windows server 2008 r2. I have the correct patch file, but when I run the patch, i get the Windows Stand Alone Installer error:

"The update is not applicable to your computer"

Comment: Download it again for giggles http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=652eea96-c2e8-4548-8f9a-40964e5e6a74

Comment: i do that 3 times and dont work

Comment: KB4034664 is latest version. look if you already have this update installed. if yes, the old update is not needed

Answer (score 0):

This is a monthly, security only quality update for March 2017.

It is included in the monthly cumulative update for March 2017 and all future security or cumulative updates released since then.

Your system already has an update that included this update installed, and you are being told it is not needed.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4012212/march-2007-security-only-quality-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows

Comment: is the first time the server install an update because it had the window update with trubless. the latest from security is KB2840149 from 22/04/2013 and KB2998812 from 14/10/2014  i think is strange that those are the latest updates in the window update, so i don´t think it is actually instaled. I try to install KB4012212 to avoid wannaCry in the first place and the updater showme that message, then i search for updates, install all that he saw but nothing.

Comment: i´m searching the updates by the catalog because the updater of the server see nothing, how can i do to search the July cumulative patch

Comment: Check if https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034664 is installed otherwise she install it

Comment: i try with KB4034664 and i get the same result: "The update is not applicable to your computer", I really dont know wath to do.!!!!